# Removing line feeds or carriage returns from excel with perl

Tags: perl, newline, carriage-return, linefeed

whenever I try a read a row in a .csv file it stops treating the row as a single row and stores it in multiple arrays, as supposed to just one. What i'm seeing is as I read a .csv file it seems to containg some carriage returns/ these weird squares when i open it in notepad. I want to remove these characters from the file so that i can properly read the .csv without it exiting too early. How would I go about doing this with a perl script.

Comment: It is difficult to answer without seeing an example of the format of the .csv you are having problems with, and also exactly what characters cause the problems for Excel. With that information it is easy to write a perl script to strip the problematic characters from the .csv.

Comment: How are you "reading" the file? Are you using [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Text-CSV) or [Text::CSV_XS](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Text-CSV_XS)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clean up trailing whitespace with the chomp() function in perl.  You can use something like this to chomp all trailing whitespace and replace it with a single newline:

```
perl -ne 'while(chomp) { } print "$_\n";' filename.csv
```

Comment: The `-p` option automatically prints, if you want to do a manual print, use `-n` instead to avoid confusion. Or do `$_ .= "\n";`

Comment: Correct!  Thank you.  (Edited to reflect.)

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to read the whole file as one line, simply disable the input record separator:

```
local $/;
my $file = <>;
```

That is, if you wish to use the data inside perl. If you simply wish to change the input file for other programs to use, and you do not care about the line feeds/carriage returns:

```
perl -pi.bak -we 's/[\r\n]+//g' input.csv
```

This will do an in-place edit of `input.csv`, and save a backup in `input.csv.bak`. Be aware that if you run this command twice, the backup is overwritten, so save a proper backup somewhere else.

I would only recommend this if you know that these symbols should not be there.